# Change language learnr tutorial

Tags: r, learnr

I've made a small tutorial with the learnr package (+ gradethis) in R. The buttons for the tutorial are currently in english (e.g. submit answer, run code). Since my tutorial is in Dutch, it'd be better if the buttons were also in Dutch.

Does anyone know if there's any way to change the button language? And possibly also change the language of the praise given by the gradeR package.

Thanks in advance!